# Null Hypothesis Appearing in Everyday Life

Tags: logic, philosophy-of-science

What are examples of a Null Hypothesis we use in everyday life but do not recognize?

Answer (score 2):

The Null Hypothesis appears in courtrooms every day:

> The presumption of innocence in law serves the same purpose as the
>   null hypothesis in science. The purpose is to produce an accurate
>   outcome in relation to the facts at hand and the seriousness of the
>   question to be settled.

This quote is part of my answer to an earlier question on this exchange, "Innocent until proven guilty - why?"

> The null hypothesis is rather an ingenious creation.... The utility of
>   the null hypothesis is that the case is not prejudged-- you are not
>   caught defending a relationship specified beforehand.

Source: Hoover and Donovan, The Elements of Social Scientific Thinking, 6th ed. (New York: St. Martin’s Press, 1995), p. 81.

This question, though, is quite broad. When you walk into your favorite eatery and you tell the server, "I'll have the usual," then you are calling upon the null hypothesis.